# Multi Domains in One Database

Tags: web-hosting

I have **One Database** with one domain. But my Database have **3 Websites** available. I want my **2nd Website** for publish in that Database. Is that possible ???

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make sure that you're not violating the terms of service with the company who is hosting your database. Having many outside domains hitting an inside database may cause some undue stress on that server that the company is not counting on or eating up more bandwidth that is allotted for that machine.

In the same breath though, if you setup some type of data layered web service which you can connect to, then your many other domains are not directly hitting the database and do essentially the same thing, but in a more ordered fashion of predictable database calls. This may not be what you're looking for, but if setup correctly it could make developing against your database much easier.